# Unity rotation object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a question about rotation, if you see this gif: https://i.gyazo.com/a1fbdbf4c125227e0bbfeda552c2981f.gif

You will notice that when he looks like a "diamond", he falls extremely slow, is there any hint for me to fix that?

My code:

void FixedUpdate() {

```
    grounded1 = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck1.position, 0.15f, groundLayer);
    grounded2 = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck2.position, 0.15f, groundLayer);
    grounded3 = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck3.position, 0.15f, groundLayer);
    grounded4 = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck4.position, 0.15f, groundLayer);

    float movex = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(movex * speed, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) && (grounded1 == true)) {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0, 15), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    } else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) && (grounded2 == true)) {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0, 15), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    } else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) && (grounded3 == true)) {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0, 15), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    } else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) && (grounded4 == true)) {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0, 15), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }


    if ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift)) && (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))) {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * -5);
    }

    if ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift)) && (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))) {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * 5);
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Vitor if you want to include an image, click Edit on your question ... look for an use the handy "Image" button, you can show the image in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not using angular velocity instead of transform.Rotate ?

```
GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().angularVelocity
```

You are using physics for jumping but rotating with transform functions , better to do both in the same paradigm.

Comment: Aweseome! Solved my question and gave me another idea, thanks!